# $|\mathcal{O}_{\sigma}^{A_n}|$ for $\sigma$ odd permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathcal{O}_{\sigma}^{A_n} = \{ a \sigma a^{-1} : a\in A_n \}$ where $\sigma = (1,2,...,n)$ for $n$ an odd positive integer. Now I want to determine the number of elements in this conjugacy class. The order must divide the order of the group $S_n$, i.e. $n!$. But how do I continue?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{O}^{A_n}_\sigma$ is the orbit of $\sigma$ under conjugation by $A_n$. By the orbit stabilizer theorem, the size of the orbit is the index of the stabilizer, $C_\sigma = \{\tau \in A_n: \tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = \sigma\}$, in $A_n$. This is the set of all permutations in $A_n$ that commute with $\sigma$ - the centralizer of $\sigma$ in $A_n$.

Here's a hint: compute the centralizer of $\sigma$ in the whole symmetric group $S_n$ first, i.e. compute $\{\tau \in S_n: \tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = \sigma\}$. How can you use this to get the centralizer in $A_n$? Remember that
$$\tau^{-1}(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n)\tau = (\tau(1)\ \tau(2)\ \ldots\ \tau(n)).$$